# Identity in n tier application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, n-tier-architecture

I'm building n tier application

I have:

> myapp.Business //for business logic
>
> myapp.Data // for data acess and repositories
>
> myapp.webApi // for web api
>
> myapp.web // for front (angular)

I want to use [Identity](https://www.asp.net/identity)

my question is that: Where it should be placed? in `WebApi` or in business? Wheren should I install that nuget packages, where should be placed `Startup` and `IdentityConfig` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better place Identity where stays Login page